# Ruby Inheritance Get Caller Class Name

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I'm so lost. I know how to use caller to get the caller method, but what do you use the get the caller class?

For example:

```
class Testing
  def return_caller_class
    return caller_class
  end
end

class Parent

  attr_accessor :test_me

  def initialize      
    self.test_me =  Testing.new
  end

end

class Child < Parent
end

class GrandChild < Child
end

test_Parent = Parent.new
test_Child = Child.new
test_GrandChild = GrandChild.new

puts test_Parent.test_me.return_caller_class     => Parent
puts test_Child.test_me.return_caller_class      => Child
puts test_GrandChild.test_me.return_caller_class => GrandChild
```

Thank you!!!

Edit:

I've tried to do the following

```
class Testing
  def return_caller_class
    return caller[0][/`.*'/][1..-2]
  end
end
```

And the output is:

```
{"
"=>Parent}    
{"
"=>Child}
{"
"=>GrandChild}
```

To explain better about my question.

I would the output to display this instead

```
Parent
Child
GrandChild
```

Comment: look at https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/161460

Comment: That question is not resolved though. The OP decided to close the question that's all.

Comment: you might want to supply self to as a parameter to use the determine the class, otherwise you can use a module and try [included](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-included)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm working with classes rather than modules and the parameter is fixed already.

Comment: Can you show the body of caller_class method? And where is it defined?

Comment: I don't know how to build caller_class. And that's what I'm wondering. How to defined caller_class.

Comment: I'm thinking of combining caller with owner, but I have no clue how the syntax would look like.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit out of my depth with this question, but I think you have made a few mistakes unrelated to the problem of getting the caller's class name. If I can help you with those things, at least you might be a step closer (if a solution is even possible)!

Firstly, it seems to me that you're calling `return_caller_class` from the main program object, not from one of those three objects you created. You have an object of class `Testing` inside an object of class `Parent`, but the method call is outside of both.

Secondly, the only reason you seem to be getting anything close to what you want (when you get output like `"=>Parent}` has nothing to do with the `return_caller_class` method. It seems as though you inadvertently created little hashes in the last three lines of your program (when you added `=> Parent`, etc), which are being output with `puts`. (Confirmed here: [Has #puts created a new hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143769/has-puts-created-a-new-hash)) If these are meant to be comments, they need a `#` before them.

PS. I found a link to this gem on another thread: https://github.com/asher-/sender. Might be worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where I got my assumption wrong. And I'll check out that link.

Comment: I tried return method(__callee__).owner and it returns 'Testing;, I'll check more info. from that link. I might find how to return the other class name.

Comment: I'll continue my research tomorrow. I got something in the way this afternoon that I had to pause my research.

Comment: Thanks the gem works nicely, but I'd prefer not relying on the gem and sadly after reading the C library, I couldn't translate it into ruby, oh well.

Comment: Oh well, put it down to a learning experience, and hopefully you can find an alternative and more idiomatic Ruby way of accomplishing what you need to.

Comment: the git project whose thread is linked to in this post is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Testing
  def return_caller_class
    self.class.name
  end
end

class ChildOne < Testing
end

class ChildTwo < Testing
end

result:
------------------------------------------------
>ChildOne.new.return_caller_class
 => "ChildOne"
>ChildTwo.new.return_caller_class
 => "ChildTwo"
>Testing.new.return_caller_class
 => "Testing"
```

Comment: Please give a brief explanation as to why this code works, big code dumps without explanation can be very confusing

Comment: This is neither big code nor confusing. It is self explanatory.