# Has #puts created a new hash?

Tags: ruby

While trying to answer another member's question, I happened across this strange behaviour:

```
puts :some_object => 'another_object'
```

Surprisingly, the output is this:

`{:some_object=>"another_object"}`

What is this new devilry? It looks as though I've created a hash using `#puts`, and without using the normal curly-bracket syntax.

I can't test this theory though, because this just generates an error:

```
puts (:some_object => 'another_object').class

# => syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting ')'
```

What's going on here?

**Edit:** Okay, thanks to bundacia's explanation, it's now easy for me to test and confirm that it's a hash (whereas I wasn't sure how to do that before):

```
def test(x)
  puts x.class
end
test(:some_object => 'another_object')

# => Hash
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Normal Ruby syntax, that has some convenience methods around hashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *are* passing a hash to `puts`. In ruby, if the last argument you're passing to a function is a hash the curly braces are optional. So your example is equivalent to:

```
puts( {:some_object => 'another_object'} )
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I must say I find that strange, but with that explanation it's easy to confirm the class now.