# Ruby -- Get defining class name

Tags: ruby

How can one get the class a method was defined in?

I've found how to look up descendents and ansestors: [Look up all descendants of a class in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393697/look-up-all-descendants-of-a-class-in-ruby)

But that doesn't necessarily get me *the defining class* (last defining class really).

I've found how to get the calling class:
[Ruby Inheritance Get Caller Class Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126628/ruby-inheritance-get-caller-class-name)

But I want the opposite. I would like how to get the defining class.

I've also tried `Module.nesting`. That gets me what I want in this case, but I worry it will be inconsistent and not acceptable in a larger codebase of which I don't have ultimate control.

```
puts RUBY_VERSION


# Test class vs super.
class Super
    def test_func
      puts "#{self.class}, #{ __method__}"
    end
end

class Child < Super
  def test_func2
     self.test_func
  end
end

Child.new.test_func
```

I had hoped for:

> 1.8.7
>
> Super, test_func

But got:

> 1.8.7
>
> Child, test_func

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7 is super old and really obsolete, so if you have any way of upgrading that would help a lot as a ton of new things have happened to Ruby since then, including, most critically, proper UTF-8 support.

Comment: Unfotunately, I'm stuck on 1.8.7 for this particular project. Worse still, I can't use gems. : /

Comment: That sounds like the opposite of fun. Hope you survive this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You asked `self.class` of `Child` object and you got it.

You need use [`Method#owner`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-owner) to return the class or module that defines the method.

```
class Super
  def test_func
    puts "#{method(__method__).owner}, #{ __method__}"
  end
end

class Child < Super
  def test_func2
     self.test_func
  end
end

Child.new.test_func
# will print: Super, test_func
```

or just

```
Child.new.method(:test_func).owner
#=> Super
```

or

```rb
Child.instance_method(:test_func).owner
#=> Super
```

Comment: This is fantastic! It works in 1.8.7 even. Thank you! I'm using this to add a log line instead of typing the class and method manually.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer. I can't find where to mark it as accepted. Maybe that's because of my fairly minuscule reputation?

Comment: Why `UnboundMethod#owner` rather than [Method#owner](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Method.html#method-i-owner), considering that `test_func` is bound to `Child.new`? jayreed1, do you need the class where it was defined programmatically or just to see it, for debugging, say. If the latter, look at the return value for `...method(:some_method)` and you will see that it is there--you don't have to tack on `.owner`.

Comment: ...For example, `22.method(:zero?) #=> #<Method: Integer(Numeric)#zero?>`, showing that `Integer#zero?`is defined in `Numeric`, whereas `22.method(:+) #=> #<Method: Integer#+>` tells us that `Integer#+` is defined in `Integer` (as `#<Method: Integer#+>` is interpreted as `#<Method: Integer(Integer)#+>)`.

Comment: Or `Child.instance_method(:test_func).owner`, so you don't have to create an instance.